# Exporting aws instance into .VMDK file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I want to migrate aws instance to vmware. How can I export aws instance into .VMDK file so that I can import it in VMware.

Answer (score 0):

I never did it but did you try the solution from [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html)

Comment: Thanks Quentin Revel, documentation was helpful.One limitation given in this documentation "You can't export an instance from Amazon EC2 unless you previously imported it into Amazon EC2 from another virtualization environment.". Does it mean i cant migrate my vm if its created on AWS???         Kindly help if you have any idea about it..

Comment: @DhirajGolhar That is correct. AWS VM Import/Export will only export an image that was previously imported. Instead, you could try [Converting Amazon EC2 Windows Instances to VMware Workstation or VMware vSphere Virtual Machines (1018015)](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1018015).

Comment: Ok my bad, as I said, I could not test the solution before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used this tool:

https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info?slug=infrastructure_operations_management/vmware_vcenter_converter_standalone/6_2_0

to convert a running ec2 instance into a format that I could download and run locally in my vmware environment.

In my case it was a windows based ec2 instance with a single 'disk'. I added a second volume/disk to the machine that was big enough to hold the primary volume, and used the tool to make the image on that new disk.

I was then able to download it start it up locally.